# Redeployed EAR in WebSphere v7 doesnt reflect some subtle code changes

Tags: java, deployment, websphere

I made some slight adjustments to my code to fix some security issues.  The changes were very small.  I also changed one link in my jsp to get rid of an old outdated website, and show the new link.

Problem is, none of my security code fixes show up in the environment. I have triple checked that the code is pushed all the way in my repository.   When I export the EAR from the WAS console, and look at the code, via 7 ZIP and notepad, all my changes are there.  However, when that very same EAR is running on the server, it magically retains the outdated flawed code.  To make this even more perplexing, my .jsp link change shows up no problem, exactly the way I intended it.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is going on here.

My gut instinct think that WAS has some kind of .class cache that isn't being cleared when the new code is deployed.

Has anyone else dealt with something like this?

Comment: Do you redeploy using Admin Console or using (custom) scripts? Deploying in Admin Console requires saving and applying changes, if you don't save your session changes, the actual redeploy won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.

My issue was utterly stupid and my fault.  I had some .class files that were saved in my /bin/ folder in my project.  When RAD went to compile my project, it just took the previously compiled .class file and decided to throw that in the .ear.  I simply deleted my .class files and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced many problems with Websphere 7. I wanted to avoid wasting time in deploying application since the flow was stop, remove, deploy and start the app again. So I started using "redeploy" feature.

This feature introduced a considerable amount of bugs since Websphere 7 redeploy didn't deploy small changes, it started causing working code inconsistency (of course, there should be an explanation for this behaviour).

So, my suggestion to you is to do the long process delete and deploy applications instead of using redeploy feature and avoid future headaches

Comment: I had only been doing that, manual add/remove.  I didnt even know there was another way.  I dont even know what the redeploy feature is. (I am a relatively new dev)

Answer (score 0):

It appears after some tinkering, I was able to force my code changes by "Updating" my application and not just adding/removing.  A simple add/remove -> stop/start would seemingly use the old files, but the "update" ear feature forced the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues.
Please note that browser keeps a cached copy of the files, so make sure if you are updating the **child jsp** then parent one should also be modified where the child is included.
Or you can try **cleaning the cache** as simplest procedure.

Comment: My JSP was the only change that was good during deployment.  It was my java files I had issues with.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in Rational Application Developer 9.0 with a local WAS 8.5 server. Code changes were not evident when testing the application locally. I tried everything: uninstalling the app and reinstalling it, stopping and starting the server, etc.

The only was I have been able to resolve the issue locally was to build a new workspace.

I have also seen this behavior on a regular WebSphere 8.5 server (by which I mean, a server which is not inside RAD). I would undeploy an application completely (including the "save changes") and then deploy a new EAR with new code, but the application would still execute old code. It was maddening. A work-around I found was to deploy the EAR with a different application name, but I won't be able to use this work-around in production. I upvoted this question, as it really could use a more definitive answer.